# installing .net core on mac

Tags: bash, macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am installing .net core on a mac and hoping to play around with it a bit on vs code.  I am following the steps from

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macosx.

However, when I run

```
dotnet new
```

I get command not found on bash.

I have followed these previous steps

```
 brew update
 brew install openssl
 brew link --force openssl
```

I have also downloaded the core package (installed successfully).  I do not see any other steps.  Wondering if I am missing a step or how to identify what is missing?

Comment: Note - install from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core not from the default purple button...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes I am not sure why the installer doesn't add the PATH to your environment.

Run below in terminal and reopen the terminal:

`echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/dotnet"' >> ~/.bashrc`

(**Note:** If you are using `zsh` or other shells, please change the above `~/.bashrc` to the initialize script of your shell, e.g. `~/.zshrc`)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem earlier today. The fix for me was to close out all Terminal windows, open a new one, then re-run the command.

Comment: you don't need additional steps..as Justin mentioned above... just try a new terminal window..it worked for me as well.

Comment: Typically, needing to re-open terminal just means that you need to source your bash profile, `. ~/.bash_profile` and then you're good to go.